# Apereo CAS 5.3.9 returns empty User Profile with Password Grant Type

Tags: cas, apereo

I have an application that gets an Access Token from CAS 5.3.9 via the Authorization Code Grant and when I query the /oauth2/profile endpoint using that Access Token, I get a full user profile as expected.

However, when I acquire my Access Token via the Password Grant Type, then I get an almost empty user profile with the client_id as its only content. Like so:

```
{
  "attributes" : { },
  "id" : "myClientId"
}
```

I noticed that a similar issue appears to have been fixed for the 5.3.X branch: https://github.com/apereo/cas/pull/3445

**My question: is this the expected behavior? Are there different classes of Access Tokens?**

To reproduce, get Access Token first:

```
curl -X GET -k -i 'https://cas-server:8443/ooscas/oauth2.0/accessToken?grant_type=password&client_id=myClientId&client_secret=secret&username=john&password=johnspassword'
```

Then get User Profile with the Access Token received:

```
curl -X GET -k -i 'https://cas-server:8443/ooscas/oauth2.0/profile?access_token=AT-5-xLbu5yX-rh0w4xwZB80vWAisSzfvdB9a'
```

Comment: I have now upgraded to 5.3.15, but the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a bug in CAS, which has been fixed for version 6 only:

https://github.com/apereo/cas/pull/4238

Integrating that patch in my version of CAS solved the problem.